# Removing and Converting Values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with multiple values:

```
wd = {'A1': ('01', '10', '0001', '0010', '0100', '1000'), 'A2':('02', '20', '0002', '0020', '0200', '2000')
```

What I'm attempting to do is make is so if the string in the values begins with '1' or '2' that my dictionary will remove it from the dictionary so '10', '1000', '20', '2000' will be removed. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
remove = ('1'), ('2')

for k,v in wd.items():
    for c in k:
        if c.startswith(remove):
            wd = {x for x in wd if x not in remove}
            print(wd)
```

Expected Output:

```
wd = {'A1': ('01', '0001', '0010', '0100'), 'A2':('02', '0002', '0020', '0200')
```

I'm also trying to make it so if I have a string:

```
mystr = '0010'
```

That my dictionary will be able to convert that string to the key in my dictionary so '0010' will become 'A1' since the value of '0010' is paired to key 'A1'. I'm able to successfully do this with a dictionary with single key,value pairs but when it comes to multiple values I get stumped.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
for k,v in wd.items():
    enstr = ''.join(str(wd.get(c)) for c in mystr)
    print(enstr)
```

Output:

```
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
NoneNoneNoneNone
```

Expected Output when I print(enstr):

```
'A1'
```

Comment: `since the value of '0010' is paired to key 'A1'.` could you better explain this please?

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. So key('A1') = values ('01', '10', '0001', '0010', '0100' and '1000'). Basically one key ('A1') has multiple values. If I have a string that matches one of the values in 'A1', I want that string to be converted to 'A1' (the key).

Comment: And why not `'01'`?

Comment: I want to keep all the values that begin with: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wd = {
   key: list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ['1', '2'], val))
   for key, val in wd.items()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble deciding who to give credit for the correct answer since Toshyak answered the other half of my question.

Comment: @Heather that's why you need to post different questions for different problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you want to remove values which start with anything given by `remove` and further you want to group the dictionary by values.. so you want a map from a value to it's group e.g. `01` -> `A1`.

The following should do this:

```
from itertools import cycle

wd = {'A1': ('01', '10', '0001', '0010', '0100', '1000'), 'A2':('02', '20', '0002', '0020', '0200', '2000')}

remove = ('1'), ('2')

for k, values in wd.items():
    wd[k] = [
        value for value in values 
        if not any([value.startswith(r) for r in remove])
    ]

lists = list()
for k, v in wd.items():
    lists += list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], zip(cycle([k]), v)))

print(wd)
print(dict(lists))
```

which gives:

```
{'A1': ['01', '0001', '0010', '0100'], 'A2': ['02', '0002', '0020', '0200']}
{'0001': 'A1', '0200': 'A2', '0020': 'A2', '0100': 'A1', '02': 'A2', '0010': 'A1', '0002': 'A2', '01': 'A1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your problem:

```
mystr = '0010'
wd = {'A1': ('01', '10', '0001', '0010', '0100', '1000'), 'A2':('02', '20', '0002', '0020', '0200', '2000')
for k,v in wd.items():
  if mystr in v:
    print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.